# Pyinstaller standalone .exe still shows console on API call even if console is set to false

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am writing a GUI app which is validating license during runtime using LemonSqueezy licence API. I use PyQt5 and QTimer to trigger validate_lic() every few minutes. Everything works fine until I make it a standalone .exe file using pyinstaller. In my .spec file I set console=False but after running an app, I can still see a console window pops up for a split second when API call is made to validate the licence.

The QTimer is connected to is_lic_valid(), is_lic_valid() calls validate_lic(). If validate_lic() returns False a modal will be showed up to the user. Inside validate_lic() I have simple API call using requests.

Is this some kind of bug or maybe I am doing something wrong?

.spec file:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('templates', 'templates'), ('icons', 'icons')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='GFP',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['icons\launch.ico'],
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)
```

UPDATE:
I found solution by myself on StackOverflow. It turns out that console flashes because of "subprocess" call. So to get rid of that i make somethig like this:

```
CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
    cmd = 'wmic csproduct get uuid'
    uuid = str(subprocess.check_output(cmd, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW))
```